# How to fix shortcuts with USB TypeMatrix keyboard on Kubuntu/KDE?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, 15.10

I'm having some trouble with my shortcuts on Kubuntu 15.10 with usb keyboard.

#### Distribution

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
```

#### Setup

Show desktop grid

> <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

[image: Meta+X to show desktop grid]

Present windows

[image: present windows shortcuts]

#### Behaviors

- Laptop keyboard

  - <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>**X**</kbd>: show the grid as expected;
  - <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>**A**</kbd>: present windows from current desktop, **not as configured** (should be windows from all desktops) ;
  - <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>**Q**</kbd>: present windows from all desktop, **not as configured** (should be only current desktop) ;
- USB TypeMatrix keyboard** ;

  - <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>**X**</kbd>: **do nothing**;
  - <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>**A**</kbd>: present windows from all desktop as expected ;
  - <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>**Q**</kbd>: show the grid, **not as configured** (should be only current desktop) ;

**N.B.:** I'm also having trouble with non-meta shortcuts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> work on main keyboard but not on USB keyboard.

#### Questions

- What is this so messed-up?

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you specify your layout is relevant.
Based on section (french) [TypeMatrix#Trucs et astuces](http://bepo.fr/wiki/TypeMatrix) section or [TypeMatrix USB-2030-B](http://download.tuxfamily.org/dvorak/documents/ez2030-usb-rev105.pdf) you can try to emulate a 106 keys keyboard.

[image: layout order is important]